# WF in Relation to Invoice

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

If a company retrieve a invoice from a commerial company and the invoice belongs to human resource. The people from accounts department retrieve the invoice and they use SharePoint to deliver it to HR's unit. Similiar in this context, how common is it to use SharePoint's workflow in relation to invoice? Any good real based example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very common. More common scenarios would be expense forms, vacation requests, purchase orders, etc. These are the key subjects to why workflows are created and used in SharePoint.

Basically, your scenario would roughly look like this:

1. Invoice received from external vendor/company
2. Goes to clerk for accounting coding (GL Number, Invoice #, electronic filing, etc.)
3. Approval request sent to person in charge of vendor or requestor
4. Approval request for user's manager if applicable.
5. Approval request goes to accounting for check to be paid, completes task when paid.
6. Notifies requesting user when approval is complete, otherwise send alerts to everyone when rejected.

Comment: Do you have to combine it with Microsoft Infopath? Do you have to use alot of customized coding with C# to achieve it?

Comment: You don't have to. SharePoint will handle the InfoPath side for the tasks that need to be completed and the form is generated whenever you create the workflow and the approval task (no further editing of the form is needed). You don't have to use c# coding. This all can be achieved though SharePoint Designer.

Comment: What context should C# be used in relation to Workflow? Any example?

Comment: If you need some advanced workflow that jumps through hoops and needs to do more those actions listed in the SharePoint Designer Workflow Actions. See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164026.aspx - If there are more advanced actions you want to accomplish in the workflow that you can't do with these actions, chances are you need to use a Visual Studios (with c#) workflow